# Pythonic way to combine simillar methods called from classmethod and instance method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-method

I have a class with methods and classmethods to create Figures. The class has also an attribute `auto_show` on class and on instance level. That's used to decide whether the created figures should be shown automatically or not. Right now I need two different methods to achieve this:

```
class MyClass:
    auto_show = True
    ...
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.auto_show = MyClass.auto_show
        ...

    @classmethod
    def _class_auto_show_figure(cls, fig):
        """Should be used only for class methods"""
        if cls.auto_show:
            fig.show()

    def _auto_show_figure(self, fig):
        if self.auto_show:
            fig.show()
```

Right now the first one is called inside all classmethods and the second is called inside all instance methods. I would like to combine them in a single method, but couldn't find a satisfactory way to do this. Is there a good solution for this, or should I stick with two separate methods doing basically the same thing? (Btw. it's important that an instance could have a different value for `auto_show` compared to the class-attribute.)

Comment: The only use of two functions is so you can conrol the `auto_show` property at two different levelss?

Comment: More or less - the class level auto_show is only there, because I have some class-methods, which cannot use instance attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html):

```py
from functools import partial

class ClassOrInstanceMethod:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        return partial(self.f, cls, instance)

class Foo:
    data = 'Foo class data'
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    
    @ClassOrInstanceMethod
    def test(cls, instance):
        if instance is None:
            print(cls.data)
        else:
            print(instance.data)

class Bar(Foo):
    data = 'Bar class data'

Foo.test() # prints 'Foo class data'
Bar.test() # prints 'Bar class data'
Foo('Foo instance data').test() # prints 'Foo instance data'
Bar('Bar instance data').test() # prints 'Bar instance data'
```

Comment: @kaja3 Took me a while to understand. Two questions. First, would you say, this approach is better compared to two seperate methods doing the same (following DRY), or might it make code harder to read? Second, why not put the check for instance or class inside the descriptor (-> def test(cls_or_instance))?

Comment: (1) I would recommend against it because generally speaking, you shouldn't want to use an instance and a class in the same way, and you shouldn't have a situation where some code doesn't know if it's dealing with an instance or a class. (2) Yes, you could write `partial(f, (cls if instance is None else instance))` and then take just the one parameter if you want. In that case the method itself can't easily distinguish between whether it is being called on a class or an instance, but if you don't need to do that then there is no particular problem with this alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with one function in the following way:

```
class MyClass: 
     auto_show = True 
     
     def __init__(self): 
         self.auto_show = MyClass.auto_show  # can be changed to (obj.__class__).auto_show 



     def fun(self=None): 
         if self==None: 
              print("class auto_show:", MyClass.auto_show) 
         else: 
              print("instance auto_show:", self.auto_show) 
                                                                                                                                                                                              

obj=MyClass()                                                                                                                                                                             

MyClass.fun()                                                                                                                                                                             
out: class auto_show: True

obj.fun()                                                                                                                                                                                 
out: instance auto_show: True

obj.auto_show = False                                                                                                                                                                     

MyClass.fun()                                                                                                                                                                             
out: class auto_show: True

obj.fun()                                                                                                                                                                                 
instance auto_show: False
```

Check whether this method meets your requirements.

Comment: Can you please remove the interpreter's `In [...]`'s from your code ? It makes it more difficult for people to use your code !

Comment: @quantummind Thanks, it nearly worked. As I use also fig beside self as function parameter, I had to give it a default value too, and call it with fig=... when using it inside a classmethod, but with these changes it works.

Comment: This works, but it hardcodes the name `MyClass` in the function, so it won't allow you to write a subclass of `MyClass` with its own class attribute.

Comment: @kaya3 No, you can do it more flexible as well. You can use `(obj.__class__)` as your class in the code inside. I will include that in the answer.

Comment: @quantummind That only affects instances, not when you call `MySubClass.fun()` if `MySubClass` has a class attribute that should override the `MyClass` class attribute.